# Returning an Object In a PHP Class

Tags: php, oop, pdo

I want to make a the following thing happen in PHP PDO OOP

```
$conn = mysqli_connect("localhost", "root", "blogger.g", "test");
$query = mysqli_query($conn, "SELECT * FROM users WHERE username='sandeep'");
$row = mysqli_fetch_assoc($query);
echo $row['password'];
```

The code which I use in the OOP way is as follows

```
class getResults{
    public $results;
    public function start(){
        try {
            $DTH = new PDO("mysql:host=127.0.0.1;dbname=test", "root", "blogger.g");
            $STH = $DTH->query("SELECT * FROM users WHERE username='sandeep'");
            $results = $STH->fetchAll(PDO::FETCH_OBJ);
            return $results;
        } catch (PDOException $e){
            return $e->getMessage();
        }
    }
}

var_dump(getResults::start());
```

I got the following output

```
array(1) { [0]=> object(stdClass)#3 (3) { ["id"]=> string(1) "1" ["username"]=> string(7) "sandeep" ["password"]=> string(8) "password" } }
```

And How Should I access each of the properties ??

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can access each row if you loop through the object with a while()-loop, for example.

```
while($row = getResults::start()) {
    echo $row->id;
}
```

One last tip: If you're already using PDO, use Prepared Statements. For your safety.

Comment: Yeah! I tried that earlier But I wanted not a loop a single line way to access It As I did in MySqli

Comment: Well, if you only have one row there is no need for a loop. You can use it the same way, just without the loop.

Comment: Yup. Thnx I think I can use the loop for listing more than One result

Answer (score 0):

Since your query yields a single row, don't use `fetchAll`:

```
$results = $STH->fetch(PDO::FETCH_OBJ);
```

would suffice. Now, store the returned value inside a variable:

```
$x = getResults::start();
```

Since, `$x` is a class object, you can access its members by `->` operator:

```
echo $x->username . "\n" . $x->password;
```

---

Alternatively, you can use `PDO::FETCH_ASSOC`:

```
$results = $STH->fetch(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC);
$x = getResults::start();
echo $x['username'] . "\n" . $x['password'];
```

Comment: Thnx in advance really helped!